# OpenRasta vs. ServiceStack vs. Nancy

Tags: .net, servicestack, nancy, openrasta

I comparing the above frameworks, and note in ServiceStack that it can output different formats, not just JSON, or XML, but CSV, SOAP, Text and HTML. However, when I compare this with OpenRasta and Nancy, in their documentation, I don't find this mentioned explicity.

Therefore, has anyone had any experience of these frameworks, and if so, can they output more than just JSON and XML?

Further, can any of these frameworks be used as web service on their own and then consumed by say a WinForm application?

Cheers

Comment: For Nancy check out this blog post http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/05/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-3/ detailing how to add your own serializers

Comment: Regarding Nancy, she can easily output csv, text and html based on my own experience. Don't know about soap. Nancy is perfectly suitable to build web/rest services that can be consumed by anythings that speaks http.